# iwlwifi driver crashing

Tags: drivers, iwlwifi

After doing an upgrade I'm getting intermittent wifi dropped connections.

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.10 (Eoan Ermine)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.10"
VERSION_ID="19.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=eoan
UBUNTU_CODENAME=eoan
```

`uname -a` -> `Linux user1 5.3.0-42-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:49:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280` -> `04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)`

Output of `dmesg`.

```
[   73.977683] kernel: Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[   73.978531] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   73.996315] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   73.996317] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[   73.996851] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   74.043627] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[   74.051715] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   74.052160] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   74.121409] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: 44:85:00:9f:09:bb
```

dmesg errors:

```
[11792.153596] ieee80211 phy8: Hardware restart was requested
[11792.698748] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[11792.849063] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[11792.929848] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[11792.952579] wlp4s0: authentication with 10:0c:6b:a6:e8:20 timed out
[11796.348552] wlp4s0: authenticate with 10:0c:6b:a6:e8:20
[11796.355129] wlp4s0: send auth to 10:0c:6b:a6:e8:20 (try 1/3)
[11796.476965] wlp4s0: send auth to 10:0c:6b:a6:e8:20 (try 2/3)
[11796.480862] wlp4s0: authenticated
[11796.485020] wlp4s0: associate with 10:0c:6b:a6:e8:20 (try 1/3)
[11796.514908] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 10:0c:6b:a6:e8:20 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=137)
[11796.524852] wlp4s0: associated
[11796.544755] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 10:0c:6b:a6:e8:20
[11796.556859] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[11801.811581] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[11801.811810] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[11801.811814] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: 6
[11801.811816] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 36.77d01142.0
[11801.811824] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[11801.811826] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000083 | trm_hw_status0
[11801.811828] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000001 | trm_hw_status1
[11801.811831] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00024200 | branchlink2
[11801.811833] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00039872 | interruptlink1
[11801.811835] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00004B86 | interruptlink2
[11801.811837] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[11801.811839] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2
[11801.811841] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x03830000 | data3
[11801.811843] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0D00CD3C | beacon time
[11801.811846] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x79B9914D | tsf low
[11801.811848] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000002 | tsf hi
[11801.811850] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[11801.811852] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0087DD38 | time gp2
[11801.811855] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[11801.811857] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000024 | uCode version major
[11801.811859] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x77D01142 | uCode version minor
[11801.811861] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000201 | hw version
[11801.811863] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x18489008 | board version
[11801.811865] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0B4F001C | hcmd
[11801.811868] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x26FE3002 | isr0
[11801.811870] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x11880000 | isr1
[11801.811872] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0800181A | isr2
[11801.811874] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00416D80 | isr3
[11801.811876] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[11801.811878] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0B40001C | last cmd Id
[11801.811880] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[11801.811882] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00004288 | l2p_control
[11801.811885] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00019C24 | l2p_duration
[11801.811887] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000003BF | l2p_mhvalid
[11801.811889] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000000E7 | l2p_addr_match
[11801.811891] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000001D | lmpm_pmg_sel
[11801.811893] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x08081421 | timestamp
[11801.811895] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00008898 | flow_handler
[11801.812063] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[11801.812066] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: 7
[11801.812068] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000067 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[11801.812070] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[11801.812073] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0086B38 | umac branchlink2
[11801.812075] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0083D08 | umac interruptlink1
[11801.812077] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0083D08 | umac interruptlink2
[11801.812079] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00004000 | umac data1
[11801.812081] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0083D08 | umac data2
[11801.812083] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[11801.812085] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000024 | umac major
[11801.812087] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x77D01142 | umac minor
[11801.812090] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC088628C | frame pointer
[11801.812092] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC088628C | stack pointer
[11801.812094] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00AF014E | last host cmd
[11801.812096] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[11801.812221] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[11801.812276] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x93391799 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[11801.812332] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x051C4062 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[11801.812387] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xCB223355 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[11801.812442] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000A056 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[11801.812497] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x9D54D929 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[11801.812554] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x888028A1 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[11801.812607] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0ED9D72F | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[11801.812662] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x08845E2A | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[11801.812718] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x03000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[11801.812775] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[11801.812834] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[11801.812892] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[11801.812968] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
```

How do I roll back a driver?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a different PCIe slot e.g. an x16 slot instead of a PCIe x1.

This solved the issue for my `ASUS PCS-AX58BT` WLAN card plugged into an `ASUS X470-PRO`

kernel: `5.5.13`